# Does a library exist with Joda Time / iBATIS integration classes?

Tags: java, ibatis, jodatime

It looks like I have to implement com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.extensions.TypeHandlerCallback for both DateTime and LocalDateTime Joda types.  This isn't a big deal, but if it's implemented somewhere else I'd rather just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no clean and flexible solutions, IMO. Jodatime dates are more flexible than the JDBC native types (`java.sql.Date`,`java.sql.Timestamp`...) and if you map to them you might be losing information (timezones). An "full" implementation, (perhaps bypassing the `getDate()`/`getTimestamp()` etc JDBC methods, using strings for example) would depend on your JDBC driver and database (and practically no database has datetime type as expressive as Jodatime's).

Here's a rather trivial implementation I did once for `LocalDateTime`. Not very tested, and it assumes your DB timestamps represent local datetimes.

```
public Object getResult(ResultGetter getter) throws SQLException {
   Timestamp date = getter.getTimestamp();
   if(date == null) return null; 
   LocalDateTime ldt = null;
   try {
      ldt = LocalDateTime.fromDateFields(date);
   } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
      throw new SQLException("illegal value for a LocalDateTime : " + date);
   }
   return ldt; 
}

public void setParameter(ParameterSetter setter, Object parameter) throws SQLException {
   java.sql.Timestamp date = null; 
   if(parameter != null) { 
      LocalDateTime ldt = (LocalDateTime) parameter;
      date = new Timestamp(ldt.toDateTime().getMillis());
   } 
   setter.setTimestamp(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this out there... we just moved our code to do this for both iBatis and myBatis.  As everyone has mentioned, timezones are not fun to work with because of the limitations in the java.sql package.  However, it is possible with the proper setup at least with LocalDate and DateTime

- https://github.com/intouchfollowup/joda-mybatis
- https://github.com/intouchfollowup/joda-ibatis

Please give feedback! This package is early

Comment: Just noticed I am late to the party: https://github.com/LukeL99/joda-time-mybatis