# Insert/select joda-time date types into/from database

Tags: java, jdbc, jodatime

What's the best way to insert jodatime objects into database using JDBC, and how to get them from it? I used to use MutableDateTime, and covert it into Timestamp before insert. But when I want to get my data from database, i got an issue.. i dont know how to do it, and how to parse types. So once again: how to insert and select Joda-Time objects into/from database.

Comment: Are your database columns a real date type (date, timestamp, etc) or are they a character string?

Comment: My columns are real date type - for this moment DATE in postgresql, but i am also interested in knowledge about other date-types and databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ORM that supports custom types. For example, [sormula Joda Time example](http://www.sormula.org/jodatime/). Implement a [TypeTranslator](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/translator/TypeTranslator.html) like **LocalDateTranslator** and all uses of corresponding class, **LocalDate**, will use type translator to convert to/from column in db.

```
@ExplicitType(type=LocalDate.class, translator=LocalDateTranslator.class)
public class StudentLD
{
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    LocalDate graduationDate;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Timestamp, and want to convert it back to a MutableDateTime, you just need

```
new MutableDateTime(timestamp.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

JodaTime objets are more expressive than the DateTime datatypes than SQL and most (if not all) databases support, hence there is no general foolproof recipe. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916942/does-a-library-exist-with-joda-time-ibatis-integration-classes)