# Wrong default fields values in java.util.calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I'm creating an instance of `java.util.Calendar` class:

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
```

`getInstance()` gets a `Calendar` using the default time zone and locale... Its 20:22 1.11.2012 in Poland right now, but when I print `rightNow` field out, the result is wrong:

```
System.out.print(rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH));
result: 10.

System.out.print(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
result: 1.

System.out.print(rightNow.get(Calendar.DATE));
result: 1.
```

I supose that in December the `YEAR` field will also be wrong. Can somebody explain that to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Month starts from 0 when you use calendar not from 1

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Comment: Thats interesting, because years starts from 1. Thats trully.. strange designed.

Comment: No, DAY_OF_MONTH gives 1 for first day http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH

Comment: @Noran: No kidding.  java.util.Calendar is _really_ weirdly designed.  Prefer JODA Time whenever you can.

Comment: Yes i know. I'm using Joda Time, but sometimes ther is a need to put instances of DateTime or others JodaTime classes into database, thats why I'm learning about callendar. If you want, you can answer me about this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168427/insert-select-joda-time-date-types-into-from-database