# Create a Java data format where spaces is inserted inbetween

Tags: java, date-format

I was wondering if Java Date format can do something like this 2 0 1 3 0 1 3 1, where a space is inserted between each digit. So far I can use this code to make it work.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
dateString = dateFormat.format(date).replace("", " ").trim();
```

But I was hoping I can just create a date format to do it all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't really look like a date format - it looks more like an int pattern

Comment: I suggest you, to use Joda-Time library. JDK date/time librares are strange and bad desiged.

Comment: @Noran, why do you think that JDK date/time *are strange and bad desiged*?

Comment: @Andremoniy See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032051/differences-between-java-util-date-and-joda-time-apis)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. Someone @Sun must have been under huge time pressure when implementing it :)

Comment: @Andremoniy as Aetheria said, or for example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184172/wrong-default-fields-values-in-java-util-calendar) - my question about one of callendar class functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is about as simple as possible.

There is no way to do this within a date format specification (not even with Joda time, as someone else mentioned).

Out of interest, why do you want spaces between the digits like that? It seems unusual?

Comment: Well, I guess I will go with what I have then. Thanks. This format is just needed for a project. It is a bit unusual lol.

Comment: +1 it seems there isn't any way to tell to `SimpleDateFormat` format date parts in such scattered way.

Comment: @Aetheria I didn't said that you can do it in Joda-Time. I recomed Joda-Time in general.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to imply that you'd implied that. And I wholeheartedly agree with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you write a subclass of `DateFormat`. You will encapsulate your formatting rule.

Comment: This is not much better then doing it outside `DateFormat`. In your case you will have to encapsulate this code (`dateFormat.format(date).replace("", " ").trim()`) into your subclass implementation

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat MSG_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd'T'HHmmssSSSZ");
...
String timeStamp = MSG_DATE_FORMAT.format( new Date() );
```

Comment: `replace("", " ")` adds a space character between all the letters and also at both ends. The `trim()` removes the unwanted whitespace from the ends, retaining the spaces inside the string.

Comment: It would be better if you will firstly check the facts, and then posting your conclusions. `replace("", " ")` works fine

Comment: point taken and lesson learned but does my answer 'answer' his question? aetheria's accepted answer doesn't even give him an answer.